# GCC takes different behavior when overflowed floating number assigned to int

Tags: c, gcc

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>


struct S { int m; } ;

struct S g_1 = { FLT_MAX * 2 };

struct S g_2 = (struct S ) { FLT_MAX * 2 };

int main() { return 0; }
```

gcc-7.2 report error at `struct S g_2 = (struct S ) { FLT_MAX * 2 };`, but just report an warning at `struct S g_1 = { FLT_MAX * 2 };`, the only difference between two statements is anonymous struct.

The gcc output:

```
a.c:7:18: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 struct S g_1 = { FLT_MAX * 2 };

a.c:9:28: error: initializer element is not constant
 struct S g_2 = (struct S ) { FLT_MAX * 2 };

a.c:9:28: note: (near initialization for ‘g_2’)
a.c:9:16: error: initializer element is not constant
 struct S g_2 = (struct S ) { FLT_MAX * 2 };
```

I know that the expression `FLT_MAX * 2` triggers undefined behavior, but why the gcc take different behavior on the two statements, is this deliberate or an unknown bug ?

Comment: If you tell us *what* errors and warnings you get, it might be easier for us to understand what's happening.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, sorry for that, I added the output of compiler GCC.

Comment: Undefined behaviour doesn't require consistency — at compile time or run time.  It doesn't even require a diagnostic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , you are right, thank you. It seems I need to read the C standard to deeply understand undefined bahavior.

Comment: Assigning out of range float to integer causes UB; and cannot appear in a constant expression